# Adjust cite format and style in RMarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I hope you are having a great time. I am working on `RMarkdown` for a report and I would like to ask a style related question. I am running the next code in a `.Rmd` file:

````
---
bibliography: bb.bib
fontsize: 11pt
nocite: '@*'
output: pdf_document
link-citations: true
---
\newpage

\section{Testing}\label{sec1}
```{r}
summary(cars)
```
\section{Demo}
This was done using @shiina and we will use some info from Section \ref{sec1} to do.
```{r}
summary(iris)
```
\section{References}
````

Everything is working fine, and I get this:
[image]

In previous graph in circle is a citation I did but I would like to change the style. In this case, only the year makes hyperlink to bibliography while the autor part `Shiina and Birge` does not link to bibliography.

Is it possible to adjust the style of citation so that I can have this: `Shiina and Birge, 2004` with both the autor and year linked to bibliography. Or would it be possible something like this: `[Shiina and Birge, 2004]` because `RMarkdown` uses `()` instead of `[]`. I do not how to set that style in RMarkdown.

The content of `bb.bib` file is the next:

```
@article {shiina,
author = {Shiina, Takayuki and Birge, John R.},
title = {Stochastic unit commitment problem},
journal = {International Transactions in Operational Research},
volume = {11},
number = {1},
publisher = {Blackwell Publishing},
pages = {19--32},
year = {2004},
}

@book{groewe2001,
  title={Stochastic unit commitment in hydro-thermal power production planning},
  author={Gr{\"o}we-Kuska, N. and R{\"o}misch, W.},
  year={2001},
  series = { Preprints aus dem Institut f{\"u}r Mathematik },
  publisher = { Humboldt-Universit{\"a}t zu Berlin, Institut f{\"u}r Mathematik },
}
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a csl field to your YAML header as a link to a [csl file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_Style_Language) which defines the style:

```
---
bibliography: bb.bib
fontsize: 11pt
nocite: '@*'
csl: cslfilename.csl
output: pdf_document
link-citations: true
---
```

[See here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html) for further examples. There is a long list of [csl files on Github](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles) and all of them are [modifiable](https://citationstyles.org/developers/).

Comment: Thanks @Mikko, could you please suggest me one csl file which is closed to my desired style?

Comment: @Duck A very good point. I got busy at work. Will see if I can find a solution later. If I cannot or if someone finds it before me, I will delete this answer.